# How can you show that each new line drawn on a plane creates another $k+1$ regions?

Tags: geometry, induction

The questions is

> If $n$ straight lines are drawn on a plane such that each line intersects every other line and no three lines have a common point of intersection, then the plane is divided into $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$$ regions. Prove this by using mathematical induction.

I did the base case, but I do not know how to show that if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true. The worked solutions say that the addition of another line creates another $k+1$ regions. How do they get that?

Thanks

Comment: @ThomasGrubb, you're right, thanks, I hadn't seen that

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, how do you make the question like that?

Comment: If you click edit (at the bottom of your question), you can see how I did it.  Also, you may find it useful to read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, I'll look at that